# Why does the calculus derivation for Universal Gravitational Potential Energy not follow calculus laws and become $W=GMm/r$ instead of $W=-GMm/r$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, newtonian-gravity, work

So we know that Universal Gravitational Potential Energy is $U=-Gm1m2/r$ where $G$ is the Gravitational Constant and $r$ is the distance between centers of mass. However, the derivation has me confused. The derivation goes like this: dw is a very small amount of work to move an object infinitely far away from a very small distance dx into another object's gravitational field.

dw = F * dx

Take the integral of both sides

w = Integral r(center of object) to infinity of F*dx

w = - Integral infinity to r of F*dx(switching direction)

w = - Integral infinity to r of GMm/x^2 *dx

w = - GMm * Integral infinity to r of 1/x^2 *dx (Constant rule)

w = -GMm(-(1/r)+(1/infinity))  (Power rule and Fundamental Theorm of Calculus)

W = GMm(1/r)

W = GMm/r

which is not correct. I probably messed up some variables and did some illegal math but could someone explain what I did wrong?

Comment: Integral of $x^p$ is $x^{p+1}/(p+1)$ here p=-2 hence there is no 2

Comment: Welcome to SE. Your equations are badly formatted and very hard to read. Please use the formatting tools provided by this site. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using the wrong convention. Gravitational potential energy is negative  the work done by the gravitational force as the second body moves from infinity to the point which is r distance away from the first point mass. This is so because we've arbitrarily taken the zero PE at infinity.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).